# Mail for Windows 10 only receives, never sends

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, gmail, email-client, microsoft-surface-3

I have a surface 3 tablet which comes with an e-mail application built-in.  Composing messages generates a "sent from Mail for Windows 10" signature type of line in the e-mail.  That's fine.

But outgoing mail just sits there in the `outbox` and never gets sent.  This is for a gmail account which otherwise works fine.  This client on this tablet receives e-mail fine -- it just can't send.

I suppose I could manually enter `IMAP` connection parameters, but that seems silly.

I'm fine with using the built-in client, which, presumably, is an `outlook` variant.

Comment: You likely need to enable “smtp requires authentication” or however that’s named in the built-in clients settings.

Comment: it finally did send...eventually.  I think it took ten minutes?  Not sure.